# UITableViewCell spooky action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Let's start right off with some code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Produit *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:object];

    return cell;
}
```

In a cell, I add a subView of type Produit, which is a subclass of UIView. This is how it looks like:

[image]

Editing all the stuff works fine except for when there are more cells than the size of the screen can allow. When that is the case, if I try and modify some info in one of the cells, it's as if the new info is added on top of the old one like this:

[image: second image]

In this image, only the Button acts spooky but sometimes the text fields also appear on top of each other. What's more is that if I modify the cell on top, then if I scroll to the bottom of the table view, the last cell also gets modified. Last thing: when I add more cells after having produced this glitch, some of the new cells get the same 'Category' as the glitched one, it's like it's making a copy of it and puts in 'Category' the glitched title...

Can someone explain what's happening? How can I fix it? Here is some more code( not all of it, just the table view configuration)

```
-(void) addNewProduit:(UIBarButtonItem*) item {
    if (!self.objects) {
        self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    Produit* product = [[Produit alloc] init];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 44);
    [product setFrame:frame];
    [product initView];
    [self.objects insertObject:product atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, everything is done programatically, no storyboards involved.

Comment: Did you implement prepareForReuse in your cell? Make sure your cells are getting cleaned up before you reuse them. You keep adding subviews to the contentView but never remove them.

Comment: @MikeTaverne The OP is using `UITableViewCell`, not a subclass.

Comment: @Aaron Brager you are right, I missed that. The problem is the reuse of old cells as your answer below explains better than I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:` gives you a cell, which might be a new cell, or it might be an old cell that's previously been shown, but has scrolled off the screen.

One quick fix is:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"forIndexPath:indexPath];

Produit *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];

[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:object];

return cell;
```

This will resolve your issue in the least efficient way possible. It is likely to cause jittery animation when you scroll really fast, especially on older devices. I just intend it as an illustration of the problem you need to solve.

A more appropriate solution would reuse the view if it's already there, instead of creating a new one each time.

`self.objects` appears to contain views, which defeats the purpose of UITableView's really fast scrolling setup. You should just include data objects there, and then configure the views for an individual cell when it's time to show that one cell. IE, you don't want a view for each data object, you want 6 views that adapt to which data object currently needs to be displayed.

Comment: Yes thank you very much, it did work. Also, I didn't know that the method could give you old cells. For now I'm gonna use the inefficient method you provided. I'll probably change it later though, but again thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are always adding more views when you re-use a cell by `[cell.contentView addSubview:object];`.    One solution might be to tag the view when you add it and then remove any subview with the appropriate tag before adding another one.